# how to pass more parameters in nsrange for checking range of strings in iphone

Tags: iphone

i want to check whether string present `.png`,`.pdf`,`.html`for that i m using

```
 NSRange foundRange = [stringrangeOfString:@"pdf"];
```

for 1 parameter that is @"pdf",its working but i 
                  want to check for  `@"png"`,`@"html"` and more parameters

Here is code now m using `NSRange foundRange = [string rangeOfString:@"pdf"];`
is their any code for that
..plz let me know
thanks

Comment: Please ask a readable question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a foreach statement

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", nil] 
foreach(NSString *str in arr)
    //bla
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to get them into an NSArray.After that use a for loop and go trough it.

Obs : range will get you the first apparence.I;m guessing you want to check the extension. Take "a.pdf.asd" as an example.This is not a pdf document.
You can try using the pathExtension method for checking,or rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options: with NSBackwardsSearch mask

Answer (score 0):

What the problem is here is that you are trying to check the extension of three types, but only giving one, so of course it will only work for one type, in this case pdf. As others have mentioned using an NSArray with the values .png,.pdf,.html loop through and check each case. Then you will have your answer that you require.

If you ever need to check for more parameters, easy add it to the NSArray, and a loop statement will do the rest for you.